# UNIX shell: sort a string by word length and by ASCII order ignoring case

Tags: shell, unix, sorting, command-line, awk

I would like to sort a string by length and then by ASCII order(upper and lower case are equal) with a unix command.

```
string = [a-z][A-Z][0-9]
```

For example:

```
"A a b B cc ca cd" : 
=> A a b B
=> ca cc cd

"Hello stackoverflow how are you today"
=> are how you
=> Hello today
=> stackoverflow
```

Comment: +1 interesting problem...

Comment: Added a single process solution using `GNU awk`. If you're interested see below. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote an ugly (maybe) `awk|sort|awk` line to do the job. it could be done in one awk process too, however, I am a bit lazy, just go to the dirty and quick way.

```
echo yourStr|awk '{
split($0,o); for(x in o) print length(o[x]),o[x]}'|sort -n|awk '!p{printf $2;p=$1;next}$1==p{printf " "$2}$1!=p{printf "\n"$2;p=$1}'
```

let's take an example:

```
"Hello stackoverflow how are you today foo bar xoo yoo ooo"
```

try with above line:

```
kent$  echo "Hello stackoverflow how are you today foo bar xoo yoo ooo"|awk '{
split($0,o); for(x in o) print length(o[x]),o[x]}'|sort -n|awk '!p{printf $2;p=$1;next}$1==p{printf " "$2}$1!=p{printf "\n"$2;p=$1}'
are bar foo how ooo xoo yoo you
Hello today
stackoverflow
```

test with your first example:

```
kent$  echo "A a b B cc ca cd" |awk '{
pipe quote> split($0,o); for(x in o) print length(o[x]),o[x]}'|sort -n|awk '!p{printf $2;p=$1;next}$1==p{printf " "$2}$1!=p{printf "\n"$2;p=$1}' 
a A b B
ca cc cd
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    IGNORECASE=1
}

{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        a[length($i)][$i]++
    }
}

END {

    for (i in a) {
        b[x++] = i + 0
    }

    n = asort(b)

    for (j=1;j<=n;j++) {

        m = asorti(a[b[j]],c)

        for (k=1;k<=m;k++) {

            for (l=1;l<=a[b[j]][c[k]];l++) {
                r = (r ? r FS : "") c[k]
            }

            s = (s ? s FS : "") r
            r = ""
        }

        print s
        s = ""
    }
}
```

Results using your input, concatenated:

```
A a B b
ca cc cd
are how you
Hello today
stackoverflow
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[length($i)][$i]++ } END { for (i in a) b[x++] = i + 0; n = asort(b); for (j=1;j<=n;j++) { m = asorti(a[b[j]],c); for (k=1;k<=m;k++) { for (l=1;l<=a[b[j]][c[k]];l++) r = (r ? r FS : "") c[k]; s = (s ? s FS : "") r; r = "" } print s; s="" } }' IGNORECASE=1 file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a zsh one-liner:

```
zsh -c 'for w (${(oi)$(<&0)}) z[$#w]+="$w "; print -C1 ${z% }'
```

given text on stdin, this produces the desired output from both test cases, leaning heavily on IFS splitting and array expansion flags.